# How to check if a string is one of several distinct values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

i have a string variable which can only contain 6 different values. I want to check if it contains one of the first 4 values or one of the 2 second values.

Is there a more elegant way than this:

```
if string.eql? 'val1' || string.eql? 'val2' || string.eql? 'val3' || string.eql? 'val4'
  ...
elsif string.eql? 'val5' || string.eql? 'val6'
  ...
end
```

Maybe something like `if string is in ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']`?

Comment: This was useful to somebody today :thumbsup:

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use `include?`:

```
if ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'].include?(string)
```

Comment: Ah, the other way around. I think it's quite elegant, thank you.

Comment: I would prefer `Array#index` for less keystrokes.. for this scenarios. :)) Same tastes.. I feel :D

Comment: For strings, you could even shorten it up further by using `%w(val1 val2 val3 val4)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
case string
when *%w[val1 val2 val3 val4]
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#index`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#index-instance_method)

> Returns the index of the first object in ary such that the object is == to obj.***Returns nil if no match is found.***

```
puts "something" if ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'].index("val1")
# >> something
```